# Rellenar un datagridview desde un array

Tags: c#

Tengo un datagridview que quiero rellenar con un array, para ello hago lo siguiente:

```
BindingSource CantonesBindingSource;
CantonesBindingSource = new BindingSource(ConfData.TcCnf.TcCnfArray, null);
oTcConfig.dataGridViewTcCnf.DataSource = CantonesBindingSource;
```

De esta manera me rellena el datagridview con el array. El problema es que el título de las columnas no es el que yo quiero.

Yo ya he creado mi datagridview de antemano con los nombres de las columnas que deseo y quiero que me rellene estos campos no que me los cree de nuevo (es un array de objetos donde cada columna es un atributo de ese objeto). No se si me he explicado bien.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto es lo que quiero que me llene

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto es lo que me crea. Quiero que se rellenen los campos no que se cree uno nuevo

Alguna solución?
Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Al cargar un datagridView a través de su DataSource, las columnas se generan automáticamente con el nombre de las variables del objeto que le pasas aunque hayas creado tu por diseño.

Una opción que tienes es, una vez cargado, le puedes cambiar el nombre a tus columnas por código de la siguiente manera:

```
oTcConfig.dataGridViewTcCnf.Columns["IdTc"].HeaderText="NombreColumna";
```

Lo malo de esto es que tienes que cambiar el título de las columnas una a una.

Otra cosa a tener en cuenta si haces esto es que, luego, si quieres hacer referencia a estas columnas su nombre no ha cambiado por lo que aunque hayas cambiado el nombre tendrás que acceder de la siguiente manera:

```
oTcConfig.dataGridViewTcCnf.Columns["IdTc"].Cells ...
```

Comment: De acuerdo gracias!

Comment: No es así. El `DataGridView` únicamente genera las columnas de forma automática si tiene la propiedad `AutoGenerateColumns` a `true`. Y sí que hay forma de asociar las columnas creadas en tiempo de diseño a las propiedades del origen de datos a través de la propiedad `DataPropertyName` de la columna.

Comment: He puesto que genera automáticamente las columnas porque al generar un datagridview, como bien has dicho, por defecto tiene la propiedad autoGenerateColumns a true.

Comment: Efectivamente, pero esta propiedad únicamente genera columnas para las propiedades que no tengan ya una columna asociada. En este caso lo que le faltaría a @Xim123 es asociar las columnas creadas en tiempo de diseño a las propiedades del origen de datos a través de la propiedad `DataPropertyName`

Answer (score 0):

El `DataGridView` tiene una propiedad `AutoGenerateColumns` que por defecto tiene el valor `true` y que hace que se generen las columnas de forma automática a partir del origen de datos.

En este caso, por cada propiedad del objeto, el `DataGridView` comprueba si existe una columna para dicha propiedad y, si no es así, la crea. La forma en la que puedes asociar una columna creada por ti a una propiedad es a través de la propiedad `DataPropertyName` de la columna. Si el `DataPropertyName` de la columna tiene como valor el nombre de una propiedad del origen de datos el `DataGridView` utilizará esta columna en lugar de crear una nueva.

En cualquier caso, si vas a crear las columnas de forma manual, es recomendable poner a `false` la propiedad `AutoGenerateColumns` del `DataGridView`. De esta forma evitarás, por ejemplo, que te cree columnas para propiedades que no quieres mostrar.

Otra opción es la de dejar que el `DataGridView` genere de forma automática las columnas y recorrerlas después para establecer sus propiedades (texto de cabecera, ancho, ...).

Salvo en prototipos o pruebas yo te recomendaría el primer sistema. Es más claro, tienes mayor control y es menos propenso a errores.

Comment: Entonces debo poner a false la propiedad de AutoGenerateColumns y asociar mi array al datagridview mediante DataPropertyName verdad?

Comment: No. El array lo sigues asociando mediante la propiedad `DataSource`. En la propiedad `DataPropertyName` de cada columna es donde indicas qué propiedad del objeto visualiza esa columna.

Comment: No veo la propiedad de AutoGenerateColumns, solo autoSize

Comment: De acuerdo voy a probar aver si me sale Gracias!

Comment: Ya me sale sin cambiar lo de AutoGenerateColumns. Gracias!

Comment: Pero ten cuidado. Si dejas la propiedad `AutoGenerateColumns` a `true` y en el futuro añades una nueva propiedad a la clase de los objetos del array se generará de forma automática una nueva columna en tu grid. Si eso no es un inconveniente no hay problema.

Comment: Por cierto. Acabo de mirarlo y efectivamente la propiedad `AutoGenerateColumns` no aparece en la ventana de Propiedades en tiempo de diseño, pero puedes modificarla por código.

Answer (score 0):

Para hacer esto, revisa las propiedades de tu datagridview, o mejor dicho de las columnas que agregaste. Si en el datagridview le colocaste de header "Nombre de la Persona" y en un arreglo tiene "NomPer", todo lo que tienes que hacer es editar las columnas del datagriview, elegir la columnda "Nombre de la Persona" y buscar entre las propiedades la que dice DataPropertyName y le asignas "NomPer", automáticamente esta columnda quedará bindeada a ese indice de tu arreglo. Todo lo que queda por hacer es asignarlo al datagridview de la siguiente manera:

```
datagridview.DataSource = TuArreglo.ToList();
```

Y eso es todo, si en tu arreglo tienes 6 elementos como ser id, nombre, fecha, etc. Pero sólo quieres mostrar los que definiste en tu arreglo, lo que debes hacer es:

```
datagridview.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
datagridview.DataSource = TuArreglo.ToList();
```

Esto evita que genere las columnas por su cuenta y sólo creará las que bindeaste.

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: Gracias! Si quiero hacerlo viceversa como podría hacerlo? MiArreglo = datagridView.Toarray?

Comment: Si queres, abrí una nueva pregunta y te contesto por ahí :)